# Exported ZFS Pool Unavailable

Tags: zfs

Some time ago my ZFS pool became unavailable and I tried a few things to get access to the files on it to remove what I could. I gave up as I have limited knowledge of ZFS. However, I am in the process of setting up a new server and I would really like to at a minimum recover what is on the apparent two good drives before setting up a new system.

When I do a zpool list I get some rpool listed, however my large tank pool RaidVol is not listed. But when I use a zpool import I get the following:

```
pool: RaidVol
id: 16881038089561338671
state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are missing from the system.
action: The pool cannot be imported. Attach the missing
    devices and try again.
see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-3C
config:

    RaidVol                  UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      raidz1-0               UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
        c6t0d0               ONLINE
        c6t1d0               ONLINE
        4996290435585416026  UNAVAIL  cannot open
        c6t3d0               UNAVAIL  cannot open
```

Is anyone able to assist with either getting the files off or getting this pool back up. I have some smaller 1TB drives I could replace the last two drives with if possible, but from memory, only the third drive is actually buggered...

Cheers,
Jeff

UPDATE:

```
pool: RaidVol
id: 16881038089561338671 
state: DEGRADED 
status: One or more devices are missing from the system. 
action: The pool can be imported despite missing or 
    damaged devices. The fault tolerance of the pool may be 
    compromised if imported. 
see: illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-2Q 
config: 

    RaidVol                  DEGRADED 
      raidz1-0               DEGRADED 
        c6t0d0               ONLINE 
        c6t1d0               ONLINE 
        4996290435585416026  UNAVAIL  cannot open 
        c6t3d0               ONLINE
```

Not sure what to do from here, even if the only thing I can do is get access to get the files off, I would be forever grateful...

Comment: You're missing _two_ devices. What happened to them?

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm not, which has led me to think that maybe something has happened to the SATA chassis... I'm investigating that now.

Comment: Okay, I now have all but one device available. One was a bad disk, which I have removed. However, it was a 2TB disk and I only have a 1TB disk to replace it with, will this be a problem?

Comment: pool: RaidVolid: 16881038089561338671
  state: DEGRADED
 status: One or more devices are missing from the system.
 action: The pool can be imported despite missing or damaged devices.  The
        fault tolerance of the pool may be compromised if imported.
   see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-2Q
 config:

        RaidVol                  DEGRADED
          raidz1-0               DEGRADED
            c6t0d0               ONLINE
            c6t1d0               ONLINE
            4996290435585416026  UNAVAIL  cannot open
            c6t3d0               ONLINE

Comment: Are there no ZFS experts around who might have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?